# Xcode doesn't accept my github token eventhough I'm logged in

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to clone a new SPM and Xcode keeps complaining about my GitHub credentials saying:

"Authentication failed because no credentials were provided"

[image]

I tried tapping the SSH, creating new tokens, adding in my `git config --global`:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

As you can see in the picture above I'm logged in and even have setup SSH, and the beautiful Xcode doesn't like it... What is even more weird is that if I download another app I have and open it like new from Github it will automatically clone the SPM that the project has, but it won't let me add new ones because of the auth issue.

Any idea what might this be...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Github is changing the way encryption works or something on XCode happened after the new release. In any case, what I did to solve it was:

1. I removed my RSA key from the system, github and XCode GitHub account
2. Generated a new key using the latest (changed) standards by Github (ECDSA keys)
3. Updated key chain access

https://blog.arturofm.com/setup-github-vsc/ on how to do all this, in case anyone needs it step by step